# Laravel 8: AJAX Athentication in non-SPA app

Tags: laravel, api, authentication

I'm writing a non-SPA app that needs to use an internal API. The API is called via AJAX requests. This is to provide the user with suggestions as they are typing, so I don't want the page to be reloading. The user must be logged in to access the API. The API doesn't need to be called from any other origin.

I have successfully got it working using Sanctum and API tokens. When the user logs in, I generate a token and store it in the browser session, and then send it with the Bearer header. This seems to work but is it the right approach? Should I just using the built in or web auth? I've been reading the docs but have just been getting kind of confused with all of the options.

Comment: Overall this sounds like a good plan but it depends how you verify the token on the server-side. Ideally you'd have a very quick way

Comment: @apokryfos It seems like Sanctum handles that part. Although I can tell you that the tokens are stored in a db table called personal_access_tokens.

Comment: Well connecting to the db and reading from a table may be a slow(ish) operation in the context of an autocomplete. Not sure if there's a better and secure alternative. Maybe if you used encryption from [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/encryption#using-the-encrypter) you could verify a token without looking it up by verifying it was encrypted by your application's key